# Serial upvoter on the loose

Tags: support, reputation

Some time ago (in January), I noticed a (-200) reputation change due to voting reversal. Someone just upvoted 20 of my posts within 5 minutes:

[image]

I thought this was an isolated event, perhaps a user who was after a voting badge. But, looking at my recent reputation history, I see that the voting didn't stop, the pattern just became more careful:

[image][image][image]

I see it always happens around the same time, though not every day. The number of upvotes varies, sometimes it's just 3 or 4, sometimes around 10 as in the screenshots above.

Could the mods please take a look at this?

Note to my mysterious benefactor: I'm sorry if I come across as ungrateful, especially if this post gets you punished for all the good you've been selflessly doing to me. Truth be told, I don't even care that much about the reputation I have, as long as it's above 2000. Please stop this and let everyone have just the votes they deserve, OK?

Comment: I "serial upvoted" several of your answers back in mid-March as a result of [this Q&A](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/122158/83790). Here's why: I use the Lite distro exclusively, and was unaware that the other distros (by default) actually force manual data entry during the initial boot process. Your answer made me aware of that (ref `piwiz`), while my answer got the 100 "Bonus Points". I felt I owed you something for that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The system does have algorithms in place to detect voting rings (people who mutually upvote everything others in the group do, which corporate entities have actually engaged in in the past) and such things.  Reversals might have something to do with that (presuming this is distinct from "deleted user").  I'm not going to identify your biggest fan, nor I am going to contact that person as they aren't doing anything wrong as far as I can tell.

The only potentially interesting thing here is the implication that someone(s) may have cast a lot of votes for you and then decided to reverse them.  The information I can access is static (ie., shows the voting relations that exist now); I can't identify patterns over time (unless I keep my own records somehow, which I am not interested in doing). If you really wish to pursue this you should take it up on Meta.SE where staff can decide if they need to do something.

Comment: I don't mind having a fan, it's a bit sad they look like a script :( Frankly, I don't want to spend my time investigating this, just wanted to let you guys know what I have discovered.

Answer (score 1):

I have noted the serial upvoter over the last year - not from looking at my own posts, but because this serial pest is causing other problems. I had assumed this was a points hound.

The serial upvoter seems to upvote practically every question, including poor, off-topic posts which get close votes by experienced members.

Unfortunately this causes unanswered questions or questions with no accepted answer (including by unregistered users) to keep repeatedly popping up in the Active queue, and not enough members vote to close.

The serial upvoter still seems to be active. One recent example seems to have no saving graces, but is upvoted.  [How to process arguments passed to a service](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/127725/how-to-process-arguments-passed-to-a-service)

Answer (score 1):

There may be something pathological about this thread. I'm not sure what it is yet, but I'm going to do some research for the Inquisition that will surely follow.

Comment: Let me know if you need data from my account. I can tell you my voting shower is still active, though voting reversal apparently became more aggressive too.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev: Oh - sorry, this was not an entirely serious comment/answer. We have a saying in my country (one of them anyway) about "looking a gift horse in the mouth".

Comment: Another way of approaching your question is to ask, "Why am I getting these upvotes? - What is the motivation?" You might consider the point that high-rep users are a necessity for a successful SE, and RPi is a bit of an "odd lot" compared to some - by that I mean there aren't a lot of Q&A with over 1K votes, or users with >300K rep. You might also consider that not all of the contributors in the SE community are "paid" in rep - some actually receive monetary compensation. This is a business after all. Now ask yourself, "If I made my living from SE, what would I do to attract talent?"

Comment: And so there needn't be anything conspiratorial about this - perhaps it's just "good business"?