# Serial voting penalty

Tags: discussion, bug

I've gotten a -30 point hit on rep just now due to "serial voting". The explanation is generic, and really doesn't help me understand what this is all about. I work hard to to treat everyone with disrespect, so I don't understand why anyone would try to favor me with "serial upvoting"! Questions and comments follow & feedback solicited:

Does the "guilty party" receive a warning about this?

The rule would seem to discriminate against contributors for doing nothing wrong except submitting a few good answers.

Is `3 votes` seriously considered serial voting? That seems a rather low bar to me!

##### Afterthoughts:

After reading Ghanima's answer - and the link he provided for what I suppose is *the offical word* on the matter of [voting fraud](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me/126857#126857), it appears still more flimsy, useless, ineffective and possibly unfair. Of course it's impossible to make an individual judgment on the fairness of it because ***it's a secret***. Some of the comments to the [voting fraud post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me/126857#126857) are interesting, and point out some of the fallacious thinking going on at *corporate*.

But to me, the contradiction in the [voting fraud rules](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me/126857#126857) that is most indicative of the extremely low level of care and thought that went into this drivel is this:

1. Note the heading **"The votes can be re-cast."** It explains that, *"Votes reversed by the detection script can be re-cast by the user at a later time, ..."*.
2. But then in the very next bullet, **"There is no automated punishment or notifications."**, it says, *"if they [the serial voter] only downvoted questions *or had only upvoted things*, they will not be notified in any way"*.

Is this an exemplar of the mentality that gets paid to police SE? It's laughable... try to imagine the thought process in this: *"Duh, it's OK to re-vote, but let's not tell dem deir votes were removed."* What?! This would seem to **condone** fraudulent collusion, while outlawing **good will**!

Comment: "I work hard to to treat everyone with disrespect" - did you mean to type that?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: Why does that matter to you? But surely you can read some of my answers, and form your own opinion?

Answer (score 5):

This is probably the best we can get on the topic: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126857/284388

Note that:

> It is strongly preferred that you do not ask about serial voting on a
> site's meta. The details of the investigation are private and will not
> be divulged, and there's nothing that normal users can do. Such meta
> posts often lead to inappropriate speculation as to the cause, who the
> voters are, etc., and they also tend to result in people engaging in
> additional targeted voting.

How does the system detect voting fraud?

> Every night around 03:00 UTC, a voting fraud detection script is run
> that looks for patterns such as these. It basically looks for users
> who have voted on another user's posts many times. The **threshold
> number is fairly low within a given amount of time** (the exact
> mechanics are kept secret). When the system detects this pattern, all
> of the votes cast from that user to the user affected are reversed,
> and a "voting corrected" event is added to the affected user's
> reputation history to indicate what has occurred.

(Emphasis mine)

I understand that it might be frustrating but I would rather suggest to just let it go, after all it's not about the reputation.

Comment: Thanks for that link, but it actually exacerbates the issue I feel. And you're correct - it's not about the reputation - except that the people who have conjured this foolish policy have **made** it all about the rep. Nothing against you at all, but I am amazed that "voting fraud" drivel ever passed muster in serious circles.

Comment: @Seamus I understand your take on the situation and the mechanism of "voting fraud". Note however that no change to the system will arise from a discussion on our site's meta as it is a matter of the whole network. If you want to discuss the matter further with SE it needs to be taken to meta.stackexchange.com Though I can - understandably - not comment on the likelyhood of a change of policy.

Answer (score 3):

This is a pretty rare and generally trivial points wise event in my experience, but I disagree that very little thought went into the mechanism.

Presuming the boundary rate is reasonable (which based on the "pretty rare" reality, it might as well be), a naive cheater will only find out the votes were reversed *if* the person who lost them tells them -- which very strongly implies collusion. In that case, the cheater now knows in order to do this it must be done slowly, ie., instead of a whole bunch of votes in an hour, they must be spread out over days,<sup>1</sup> meaning **this throttles the rate** at which cheating can be done, effectively defanging the process unless a group of users gets very savvy about it.

Point being, that the votes can be re-cast does not mean the user can simply do it over again and it will be okay this time.  It won't. The exact same thing will happen. Unless you actually prevent the user from voting, there aren't any other possibilities.

The mechanism does't work in real time, implying if you wanted to stop Bobo when Bobo votes for Suey the third time in as many minutes, you'd have to add code to the interface, code that requires interaction with the server database, etc., and this adds strain to the interface in real time for everyone in order to catch the occasional handful of relatively beniegn cheaters.

As to the fact that no other action takes place, I'd wager "other actions" have taken place if someone does this serially on the same exchange. Even if no such further actions happen, or before they do, keep in mind the damage is being undone presumably without the perpetrators noticing.<sup>2</sup>  If they do, then that's the end -- you literally can't do it effectively, as just described.

Also keep in mind that actively keeping a specific person off the network is probably not worthwhile.  You can delete an account, we can even correlate IP addresses and such, but ultimately you can't stop someone from just creating a new account. The most efficient approach is exactly this: Automate constraints on user behaviour.

That the cheater is not told they have been caught could be automated too, but I'm not sure what the point is: If you are really breaking obvious laws there's no point in saying, hey, don't you know it is against the law to hit other people with sticks (eg.).  Everyone knows it's wrong. We just need to stop it from happening.

A little background on this (dunno if it was in any of your reading): In the past there have been software shops where the employees all have accounts, *and management has told them to promote each other as much as possible*, meaning they would all literally upvote all of each other's posts.  *Why* they would want to do that is a good question, but the main SO site has had significant problems with organized voting rings of this sort.
So what appears to be a thoughless effort at first glance may actually be a policy honed in the fire, so to speak.

---

1. Pretty sure there is actually a mechanism to catch that too, though.
2. Sort of making this a form of restrained [hellbannig](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_banning) ([see also](https://blog.codinghorror.com/suspension-ban-or-hellban/)) -- does unfair * unfair = fair, like multiplying a negative by negative?

Comment: Thanks for your answer & comments. First, 30 points isn't trivial to me. Next, I believe Hanlon's Razor explains much of the *illogical* stuff we see in social media - I hope my question reflects that. I understand and support the goal to have fair and consistent vote counts, but that outcome is not reflected in the policy as stated. I am referring to the *policy* to allow discounted votes to be recast by the serial voter, but not to inform him that they have been discounted. This virtually guarantees that *collusive* fraudulent votes will be re-cast, but *non-collusive* votes won't.

Comment: There was another Q on this subject ~ a year ago: [Serial upvoter on the loose](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2278/serial-upvoter-on-the-loose). I made a comment to the question - effectively an admission that I was what you've called a *naive cheater*. I don't regret it a bit. And as a matter of fact, now that I know @DmitryGrigoryev had votes subtracted, I think I'll go make that right again. You probably should report me to the SE Voting Police (I wonder if they can read?)

Comment: There's no need for a voting police, it's an automated policy.  And it isn't secret, either.  I do have a bit of a beef with SE largely crowd sourcing its own documentation in Meta -- although a lot of that is by employees, searching through Q&As is *not* a replacement for an indexed content hierarchy etc.  So the fact that people naively may fall for it is sort of part and parcel about how all technology users  must suffer occasionally from what might as well be considered your own naivete, because no one else actually claims to take responsibility for such.

Comment: That said, yeah, I do consider upvoting someone 20 times in 5 minutes because you liked one or two of their posts (and worse: to *reward them* for awarding you something legitimately) as abusing the system, and I would support any mechanism that effectively prevented it (as this does).  However, I agree that 3 votes in any period of time is way too low a bar.  I commonly read a set of things until I'm satisfied the info is as useful as I think then cast a set of corresponding upvotes (although, not to posts I did not read simply because of who wrote them).

Comment: Partially because of that, I don't believe it is as simple as 3 votes -- it would be way too common.  I'm not even sure this has ever happened to me, in fact, although I have lost a few times because a user was destroyed.  I might have forgotten it, but in any case, I've been a member at SO for 10+ years, currently with ~140K points spread primarily across here, there and U&L (where I was a top ten user for years) on ~3000 posts; I've answered 5% of the questions here.  I guess it might be that no one ever voted for three of them at once.

Comment: Anyway, there may well have been more to it than just three votes for you (eg., someone casting dozens of votes in a few minutes; there is a daily limit per user).   You could always try asking in Meta if you are that concerned/curious.  Keep in mind WRT the vote limit, you get a bonus if you spend them all, and no doubt occasionally people just do it quickly at near random, something that should be discouraged.

Comment: Uh - wrt `"And it isn't secret, either."`: Maybe we're reading different things? When I read  the section labeled `How does the system detect voting fraud?`, I see this statement:  `"(the exact mechanics are kept secret)."`  When I read the last para of the section labeled `What if I think I'm the victim of voting fraud?`, and it says `"It is strongly preferred that you do not ask about serial voting on a site's meta. The details of the investigation are private and will not be divulged"`... are you making a distinction between `secret` and `private`?

Comment: [Another post on SE Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130046/when-should-i-vote) seems to underscore the abject stupidity of this `voting fraud detection by lame algorithm` policy.  None of the answers suggests that voting must be done slowly over time. In fact neither of the words `time` or `frequency` are mentioned in any answer. Even in the [Help section](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote), the guidance is at odds with the time-based, poorly conceived and lame `voting fraud detection algorithm`. No `algorithm` can possibly make these personal judgments!

Comment: I understand ***why*** algorithms are used: They provide an *efficient* and *cost-effective* means to enforce rules and objectives, and they allow social-media owners to make profit. That's all fine - both are noble goals. But this `lame time-based voting fraud detection algorithm` is the product of dim or lazy minds, and insulting to all.